# How to update data using two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables gains and final_gains.

I'm wondering how I could calculate the sum of two columns and insert it into a different table...I need to be using a WHERE clause which would be inside runescape_name inside the gains table.

Like so

```
hitpoints_end_exp - hitpoints_starting_exp,
magic_end_exp - magic_starting_exp, 
range_end_exp - range_starting_exp
```

And insert the result into `final_gains.hp_gained`, `final_gains.magic_gains` and `final_gains.range_gained`

Here are my two tables

**gains**

```
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| runescape_name         | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| hitpoints_starting_exp | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| magic_starting_exp     | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| range_starting_exp     | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hitpoints_end_exp      | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| magic_end_exp          | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| range_end_exp          | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**final_gains**

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| runescape_name | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| hp_gained      | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| magic_gained   | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| range_gained   | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Sorry If I'm unclear, trying to explain the best as I can, I hope I'm clear enough

Comment: Sample data and desired results are a great way to explain what you really want to do.

Comment: I suppose the first query that comes into my head is this:

SELECT runescape_name, hitpoints_end_exp-hitpoints_starting_exp, magic_end_exp-magic_starting_exp, range_end_exp-range_starting_exp as difference

but I have no idea of how to insert the result into final_gains table

Answer (score 1):

Use an INSERT, SELECT like this:

```
INSERT INTO final_gains (runescape_name, hp_gained, magic_gains, range_gained) 
SELECT runescape_name,
       hitpoints_end_exp - hitpoints_starting_exp,
       magic_end_exp - magic_starting_exp, 
       range_end_exp - range_starting_exp
  FROM gains;
```

In order to avoid duplicate keys:

```
INSERT INTO final_gains (runescape_name, hp_gained, magic_gains, range_gained) 
SELECT runescape_name,
       hitpoints_end_exp - hitpoints_starting_exp,
       magic_end_exp - magic_starting_exp, 
       range_end_exp - range_starting_exp
  FROM gains
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE hp_gained    = hitpoints_end_exp - hitpoints_starting_exp,
       magic_gains  = magic_end_exp - magic_starting_exp, 
       range_gained = range_end_exp - range_starting_exp;
```

This is untested code, but should be close.

**Note**: I removed the first suggestion as it s not applicable to these table definitions. `runescape_name` is primary key in table `final_gains` so it has to be inserted/assigned as well.

Comment: You are right, may be it's too confusing ... I'll remove it; thanks for the hint :)